# Pencil.It Firefox plugin not working

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 4.0.1 on my 11.04 Ubuntu system. I have added one plugin for Firefox called Pencil.It which isn't working. How to solve that?

Comment: is the plug in even compatible with firefox 4?

Comment: ya it has written Not available for Firefox 4.0.1.But apart from that can I install and work on it?

Comment: HEHE , well there you go..

Answer (score 3):

Pencil.it doesn't support Firefox 4, it only works with Firefox 3.0b3 - 3.6.*.  There hasn't been any development since June, so it's impossible to estimate when support will land if ever.

You could try to [bypass the test](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21478/how-to-bypass-firefox-4.0-betas-incompatible-add-on-error-and-install-extensions-anyway/), but make sure you backup your bookmarks etc as things might get ugly.